# Pyinstaller creates output that is over 1GB in size

Tags: python, pyinstaller

So I'm using Pyinstaller to create an exe for my simple python program. It's pretty small 500 lines of code. The imports look like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import simple_image_download.simple_image_download as simp
import re
import os
from PIL import Image
import shutil
import openai
import datetime
import csv
from googlesearch import search
import traceback
from pathlib import Path
import random
import piexif
from fractions import Fraction
```

The problem is that the output it creates is massive. My python exe is 50MB, and it has an _Includes folder that is 1.15gb of stuff.

Is there some other way I can create a program without such huge overhead?

Comment: Look in that `_includes` folder -- which _specific_ things in that folder are using how much of the space? Once you know that, you know what parts of your dependency tree to try to prune. (If you're lucky, a lot of space will be going to content like test data that isn't needed at runtime in the first place; but you need to identify the problem before you can solve it).